# What database should I use that requires minimal software install to end-users computer?

Tags: c++, database

I'm creating dvd rental software in c++. I need three databases, one to store customer information, one to store dvd inventory, and one to store dvd rentals.

I'm creating it for my boss at a small grocery store that rents dvd's as a small side business. They don't want me installing a ton of companion software on their computer to get this running, so I need to use a database is as native to windows as possible (if that makes sense).

Also, if it makes a difference, i'm relatively new to c++ and 100% self-taught so I don't quite have the complex programming ideals down yet.

If you could suggest a database and a reference where I could read up more information on how to implement it that would be excellent!

Comment: do it in another language like C# or Java, it would be easier. use MySQL that works very well and a connector.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/). It is ideal for situations like yours, and does not require a separate installation. All you need is a library and a file with the seed database. Both of these can be installed as part of installing your product.